# Ruby 1.9.3 segmentation fault on rackspace

Tags: linux

I'm having a similar problem as "[ruby 1.9 segmentation fault on exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968951/ruby-1-9-segmentation-fault-on-exit)."

I followed the solution and updated `libselinux` with yum and have the following version installed:

```
Package libselinux-2.0.96-6.fc14.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

I am running a RackSpace machine, kernel version: 2.6.35.4-rscloud.

My C backtrace is:

```
-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x18910a) [0x7f3cdb6c010a] vm_dump.c:796
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x5eb04) [0x7f3cdb595b04] error.c:258
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_bug+0xb8) [0x7f3cdb5969d8] error.c:277
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x119865) [0x7f3cdb650865] signal.c:609
/lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x328540eeb0]
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x179272) [0x7f3cdb6b0272] ./include/ruby/ruby.h:1306
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17f31b) [0x7f3cdb6b631b] vm.c:1220
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1800d5) [0x7f3cdb6b70d5] vm.c:624
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_yield+0x44) [0x7f3cdb6bb274] vm.c:654
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0xab821) [0x7f3cdb5e2821] numeric.c:3204
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x183601) [0x7f3cdb6ba601] vm_insnhelper.c:404
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1792b4) [0x7f3cdb6b02b4] insns.def:1015
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17f31b) [0x7f3cdb6b631b] vm.c:1220
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1800d5) [0x7f3cdb6b70d5] vm.c:624
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_yield+0x44) [0x7f3cdb6bb274] vm.c:654
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_ary_each+0x54) [0x7f3cdb5622e4] array.c:1478
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x183601) [0x7f3cdb6ba601] vm_insnhelper.c:404
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1792b4) [0x7f3cdb6b02b4] insns.def:1015
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17f31b) [0x7f3cdb6b631b] vm.c:1220
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval+0x1f0) [0x7f3cdb6bbae0] vm.c:1447
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x67bfd) [0x7f3cdb59ebfd] load.c:310
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_require_safe+0x6ef) [0x7f3cdb5a02df] load.c:619
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x183601) [0x7f3cdb6ba601] vm_insnhelper.c:404
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1792b4) [0x7f3cdb6b02b4] insns.def:1015
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17f31b) [0x7f3cdb6b631b] vm.c:1220
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1800d5) [0x7f3cdb6b70d5] vm.c:624
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_yield+0x44) [0x7f3cdb6bb274] vm.c:654
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_ary_each+0x54) [0x7f3cdb5622e4] array.c:1478
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x183601) [0x7f3cdb6ba601] vm_insnhelper.c:404
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1792b4) [0x7f3cdb6b02b4] insns.def:1015
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17f31b) [0x7f3cdb6b631b] vm.c:1220
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval_main+0xaf) [0x7f3cdb6bbbdf] vm.c:1461
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x6471a) [0x7f3cdb59b71a] eval.c:204
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(ruby_exec_node+0x1d) [0x7f3cdb59c56d] eval.c:251
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/libruby.so.1.9(ruby_run_node+0x1e) [0x7f3cdb59e60e] eval.c:244
ruby() [0x4008eb]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x3284c1ee5d]
ruby() [0x4007d9]
```

Comment: Questions about server administration would be better asked at serverfault.com